# Transform time series data set to supervised learning data set

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, supervised-learning

I have a data set with time series (on daily basis) for multiple items (e.g. users).
The data looks simlified like this:
https://i.ibb.co/Pj4TnHW/trans-original.jpg (I can't post images, because of missing rep. points, sorry)

This data set has all the same attributes (e.g. measures) for each user. Those measures are taken over a time window on daily basis. Every user has its own "event date".

My goal is to transform this time series (row-oriented) data set to a dataset, which could be used for supervised learning.
My desired layout would look like this:
https://i.ibb.co/8DxYpCy/Unbenannt.jpg

Currently, I apply my solution on a dataset with ~60 measures.
So far I achieved this, by using an iteration over "user_id" and applying multiple steps with pandas.melt(), pandas.transpose() functions.
But this requires a lot of preformatting, and becomes slower with larger data sets.

Is there a better way to do my transformation? I read about this https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/ but this seems to be another type of problem...

//EDIT #1: As requested, I created the smallest possible notebook / python script, with a simplified dataset to demonstrate, what I'm doing: https://www.file-upload.net/download-13590592/timeseries_to_supervised.zip.html
(Jupyter Notebook, exported HTML-Version, sample input dataset)

Comment: It can be helpful to copy in a small amount of data, say in the form of code that defines a pandas dataframe, as well as the code you're currently working with. That way more concrete suggestions can be made!

Comment: Hi Josh, I created a jupyter notebook + sample dataset. Please find the files attacahed.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do stuff like this with [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)), it's a language well designed to manipulate rows (functional programming). You can use the library [datatable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), it's very fast. If I may ask wich column are you trying to predict ? Be careful to not predict an outcome based on present or futur data, you can only use the past :)

Comment: Thanks, I will definetly have a look at this library! In my case, I'm not planning to predict one of those time series related elements. I will always work on the already existing data, but with knowing the pattern of these measures, I know, that something happened or not (e.g. machine fault).